# AES Implementation in Ionic2

Tags: ionic2, aes

I have implemented AES encryption. Please find the below code

```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

@Injectable()
export class AesProvider {
  key: any = '';
  constructor() {
    this.key = 'asfda75vzv866@#$#';//CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("asfda75vzv866@#$#");
  }

  padOrTruncate(str: string): string {
    let result: string = '';
    if (str.length % 32 == 0)
      return str;
    result = str + '';
    while (!(result.length % 32 == 0)) {
      result = result + " ";
    }
    return result;
  }

  encrypt(plainText): string {
    let text = this.padOrTruncate(plainText);
    let encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text, this.key, {
            mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
            padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding
          });
  return CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(encrypted.ciphertext);
}

decrypt(encryptedText): string {
  let decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedText, this.key, {
                                        mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
                                        padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding
                                      }).toString();                             


 //var plaintext = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

  return decrypted;

}
}
```

The issue is The decrypted text is not same as the plain text. Could anyone please help me with this?

### Edit

1. How to generate Private key and Public Key for a user?

Thanks and Regards

Dak

Comment: Are you using the same key for both encryption and decryption?

Comment: @AnandRaj, Yes I am